# How to lock a record being updated by a user in multi user Laravel + Vuejs app

Tags: ajax, laravel, vuejs2

One way I can think of is to have a hidden field on the form to store the `updated_at` timestamp of the record being updated as `fetched_at` and then when the form is submitted compare the `updated_at` value of the database record with the `fetched_at` from the request data.

If the `updated_at` from database is `> fetched_at` return a response indicating that the record has been updated since it was fetched for edit and prompt the user for a refresh.

In this case the user will refresh the record and redo the editing desired.

Is there a better way to approach this? I mean is it possible to lock the record making it unavailable/readonly for all other users when any user is currently editing/updating the record?

Comment: something like this? https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/queries#pessimistic-locking

Comment: Why donwvote? At least let me know what's wrong with the question and why it's being downvoted. So that I can learn not to ask such questions.

Answer (score 0):

If I get it correctly then what you require is that when a user is about to update a record he should review the latest updated value before sending his update. The *fetched_at* and *updated_at* use-case should work.

Locking the record I do not think its a good idea. You will have to go through another process of unlocking the record. Like what if a user fetches the record and takes awfully lot of time to update it back or worse still if the user pulls up the record and leaves is desk to go for another errand or if for some reason the session of the user gets cut-off due to some error or internet issues etc.

You could try another way that keep polling the database and compare if at any point an update has happened to the record when a user has fetched for editing. If an update has happened then display a label message saying the record has recently been updated. Vuejs + ajax or Vuejs + axios does provide innovate ways to do the polling.

This post [here](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/vue/how-to-periodically-poll-a-back-end-api-using-vuejs) shows a method to do polling.

```
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    items: [],
    interval: null,
  },
  methods: {
    loadData: function () {
      $.get('/api/data', function (response) {
        this.items = response.items;
      }.bind(this));
    }
  },
  ready: function () {
    this.loadData();

    this.interval = setInterval(function () {
      this.loadData();
    }.bind(this), 30000); 
  },

 beforeDestroy: function(){
clearInterval(this.interval);
}
});

<div id="app">
  <div v-for="item in items">{{ item.prop }}</div>
</div>
```

In the comments they do talk about [pusher](https://laracasts.com/lessons/introducing-laravel-echo) which is something similar to nodejs *broadcast*.

Comment: Locking the record is a good idea as long as your careful about how a lock is acquired and released.

I would use a heart beat mechanism on the side that controls the lock.  If the user forgets to logout or is unresponsive for a certain amount of time the lock would automatically release.